# Export only new data since the last PostgreSQL database export

Tags: postgresql, backup, export, database-backups, pg-dump

I have a decent sized PostgreSQL database (approx 6GB & growing).  A full backup/export of the database is done every few hours via cron & pg_dump.  Specifically, can I export only the changes to the database since the last export? Or perhaps run a utility that compares the two exports and appends the differences to the original, etc?  I'm trying to save disk space and "cloud" transfer time.

Comment: PostgreSQL is ACID. You can trust it to keep your data in a good shape for more than a few hours. Change the hardware if you can't trust it.

Comment: Please ignore above comment - Mr jmz isn't yet enlightened to the Tao of Backup: www.taobackup.com

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. What you could do, is setting up WAL archiving to make incremental backups:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL

This can only be done for the whole cluster, not for a single database.

Answer (score 0):

Use differential backup solution, like for example free [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/).

But remember to store a database dump - don't store live database files, as your backup will be corrupted.